# Wcf : Where are all the responses going?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I have some REST web services implemented like this :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRESTService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetEveryone", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    EveryoneDTO GetEveryone();
}

public class RESTService : IRESTService
{
    public EveryoneDTO GetEveryone()
    {
        // [...] Some processing
        return everyone;
    }
}
```

Where is going my `everyone` object? I mean, it must happens some things to transform the objects to JSON and send them. My debbugging won't lead me any further.

I'm interested in this because, let's say, I want to process every string contained in every objects I send back (maybe for encoding purposes), how/where would I be able to implement a middleware that intercept every object and be able to alter them easily before sending them?

Comment: There are literally **tons** of docs on WCF extensibility, including custom message inspectors. You really shouldn't have missed that. E.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility/ Take a look here, for example, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions/ where you have a custom REST message inspector.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Indeed, but I have some difficulties manipulating the `Message` object format in the `BeforeSendReply` method. How did it end up like this, can't I manipulate my objects just a step before the `Message` format?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to implement a *Custom Message Inspector*.
There are two interfaces you can implement, depending on client or server side:

`IClientMessageInspector` for client and `IDispatchMessageInspector`  for server. You can implement both on same class and assembly and use what is more convenient, because message inspectors are extensions and you can configure (Web.config for  instance) which you want to use.

`IDispatchMessageInspector` implements `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply` methods, so you can intercept messages when you receive the request and before to send the reply, very usefull to your scenario.

Here is the [MSDN message-inspectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors) documetation

A simple example of implementation:

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();
        var m = buffer.CreateMessage().ToString();
        return null;
    }
```

Note that you must copy the original message, so you can extract the XML and convert to an object to your pourpose  (log, change, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, you would like to intercept WCF data output before sending it to your client.

there are various ways of doing that, what's in the link below is one of them :

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_wcf/learn-to-create-interceptors-in-wcf-services.htm

Hope it helps